# R: row names replacement

Tags: r

A data frame 'temp' is read from a .txt file. The row names are some gene IDs. There is a reference table 'grcm38' where I can find the name of each gene ID. However, there are some IDs do not exist in the reference table, therefore cannot find a name corresponds to them. The only way I can do is to run it several times to find out these IDs and explicitly remove it from searching space, but in this case I have to read the .txt again and again. There must be a smarter way. Does anyone know it? Here are my code. Thanks!

```
>library(dplyr)
>library(annotables) # mouse is grcm38
>temp <- read.csv(file='data.txt',header=T, row.names=1, sep=',')
>head(grcm38)
# A tibble: 6 x 9
  ensgene  entrez symbol chr    start    end strand biotype description 
  <chr>     <int> <chr>  <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int> <chr>   <chr>       
1 ENSMUSG…  14679 Gnai3  3     1.08e8 1.08e8     -1 protei… guanine nuc…
2 ENSMUSG…  54192 Pbsn   X     7.78e7 7.79e7     -1 protei… probasin [S…
3 ENSMUSG…  12544 Cdc45  16    1.88e7 1.88e7     -1 protei… cell divisi…
4 ENSMUSG…     NA H19    7     1.43e8 1.43e8     -1 lincRNA H19, imprin…
5 ENSMUSG… 107815 Scml2  X     1.61e8 1.61e8      1 protei… sex comb on…
6 ENSMUSG…  11818 Apoh   11    1.08e8 1.08e8      1 protei… apolipoprot…

>for (i in seq(1,length(rownames(temp)))){
  print(i)
  index = which(grcm38$ensgene == rownames(temp)[i])
  if (i == c(540,7124)) {print((paste("Cannot find symbol of ",rownames(temp)[i])))}
  else {rownames(temp)[i] = grcm38$symbol[index]}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Are you asking how to remove rows from `grcm38` that contain an `NA` in a specific column? In that case, you could do `grcm38[!is.na(grcm38$symbol), ]`; or use `complete.cases()`, e.g. `grcm38[complete.cases(grcm38), ]`.

Comment: I think `?dplyr::anti_join()` may be of use here. Always try to make your question reproducible, we don't have access to 'data.txt'...